# Frontmatter chapter title size in memoir

Tags: memoir, fontsize, chapters, front-matter

How do I specify the chapter title font size in the frontmatter of a document typeset with `memoir`? I want to set different font sizes for the frontmatter, mainmatter, and backmatter. I need to reduce the font size like in this picture.

[image]

Comment: You do not. You will have to make two different chapter styles. But as a reader, I would find it strange that the design changes throughout the doc

Comment: @daleif Even though it is not recommendable and i would leave a *huge* disclaimer, are you willing to provide a solution and get this one off the list?

Comment: @Johannes_B, not really. It is not something I think should be left in the archives for others to be inspired by. IMO when you end up with questions like this, your dealing with a broken design to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The `memoir` class has some hooks to do this without defining a complete new style.

This example has ridiculous formatting, just to show how it works. Change the font settings to what you want.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\chapter{Front}

\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\huge}
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\Large}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\itshape\Huge}

\chapter{Main}

\backmatter
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont}
\chapter{Back}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is not a good way of doing things. It should be handled using chapter styles such that these can be controlled in the preamble. Then one does not have to search through many files to figure out where the author have hidden these things. In general, IMO, any `\renewcommand` and friends does not belong in the body of a LaTeX document.

Comment: It seems overkill to define a complete new chapter style to change only a few of the many parameters (including the font changes in my example) described in section 6.5 of the Memoir documentation. I agree that repackaging the above changes in a more logical way is a good idea, if this is a "large" document.

Comment: You do know that you can start a chapter style by just calling another chapter style? And then add the changes.

Comment: I didn't know that till I read your comment. Thanks.